# Array value doesn't get updated with the posted value

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I have two php pages 'page1' and 'page2'.

1. *page1* submits a form(method="post") and sends the form values tot the *page2*.
2. *page2* updates its multidimensional array with the posted values.

**Here is the code for updating the array:**

```
// page2 //
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // Loop 1
  foreach($medewerkers as $medewerker){
      if($_POST['txtId'] == $medewerker[0]){
          $medewerker[1] = $_POST['txtNaam'];
      }
      print_r($medewerker);  // SHOWS THAT IT IS UPDATED
                             // Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => value updated ) 

  }

  // Loop 2
  foreach($medewerkers as $medewerker){
      print_r($medewerker); // SHOWS THAT IT IS NOT UPDATED
                            // Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => blabla ) 
  }
}
```

As you see in my comments, in the 'Loop 1' it's being updated it shows also that it is updated. But if I loop through the array again as you see in 'Loop 2' it shows that it is not updated.

Can you see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _“In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.”_ – http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it like this, you have to use references.
Add `&` to your first loop.

```
// Loop 1
foreach($medewerkers as &$medewerker){
  if($_POST['txtId'] == $medewerker[0]){
      $medewerker[1] = $_POST['txtNaam'];
  }
}
```

Another approach can be indexing your original array.

```
// Loop 1
foreach($medewerkers as $i => $medewerker){
    if($_POST['txtId'] == $medewerker[0]){
        $medewerkers[$i][1] = $_POST['txtNaam'];
    }
}
```

Comment: To add some background to this answer: PHP creates a copy of the element you're currently iterating and you're overwriting this copy in your original question, hence the array itself remains unmodified. Using the reference operator tells php to reference the original instance without creating a new one. This way any changes you make on the object directly apply to your array aswell. The second approach should be rather self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` loops work a bit differently; quoting from the PHP manual documentation for [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Note: Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself.

**Passing by Reference**

You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the variable. The syntax is as follows:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a);
// $a is 6 here
?>
```

Documentation: [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Applying it in your case, it should become:

```
foreach($medewerkers as &$medewerker){
// ---------------------^
  if($_POST['txtId'] == $medewerker[0]){
      $medewerker[1] = $_POST['txtNaam'];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

add this below line

```
$medewerkers[] = $medewerker;
```

after line

```
$medewerker[1] = $_POST['txtNaam'];
```

finally your code must look like.

```
$medewerker[1] = $_POST['txtNaam'];
$medewerkers[] = $medewerker;
```

Comment: this doesn't work, sorry. I think working with references like advised  above will be the best solution for me. Thanks anyway!